# generic Enum.valueOf method : Enum class in parameter and return Enum item

Tags: java, enums

I'd like to make a method that implement `valueOf` on any Enum class passed in parameter (and also wrap some specialized error/missing-name code).
So basically, I have several Enum such as:

```
enum Enum1{ A, B, C }
enum Enum2{ D, E, F }
```

And I want a method that wrap around `valueOf`. I could not find a way to directly pass an Enum class in parameter on which I could call `valueOf`. Here is what I came up with:

```
private static Enum getEnum(Class<Enum> E, String name){
    for(Enum e: E.getEnumConstants())
        if(e.name().equals(name)){
            return e;
        }
    return null;
}
```

Which I want to call with: `getEnum(Enum1,"A")`. But it does not like it:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Enum1
  location: class Main
```

Comment: isn't there a method for that - `Enum.valueOf(Enum1.class, value);`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why implement your own, when you can use Java's own implementation for this?

```
 YourEnum yourEnum = Enum.valueOf(YourEnum.class, value);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

Your method then becomes:

```
private static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum(Class<E> enumClass, String name){
    try {
        return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, name);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and you can call it with:

```
getEnum(Enum1.class, "A")
```

Comment: that method seems useful, but I still got the problem of the `getEnum` signature (I want to wrap the `valueOf` call into it to add some more code around it.

Comment: well based on the `valueOf` signature, `public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`, you would need  `private static <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum(Class<E> clazz, String name)`

Answer (score 4):

For pass classes you should use `class`

```
getEnum(Enum1.class,"A")
```

And then update method signature to

```
private static Enum getEnum(Class<? extends Enum> E, String name){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It does not correspond to the signature of `getEnum` which takes a `class<Enum>`. And if I change that for `class<?>` then `E.getEnumConstants` returns `object`...

Comment: update method signature to `private static Enum getEnum(Class<? extends Enum> E, String name)`

Comment: alright! And then I can use @Zhuinden `Enum.valueOf` too :-)

Comment: I finally selected Zhuinden answer because it returns the correct Enum type, not just an Enum.