# How to create a generic class in what I can call an Enum.valueOf() in Java?

Tags: java, generics

So I have these classes:

```java
public class DeviceInState implements MyInterface<Device> {

    private List<DeviceState> toStates(String statesString) {
        List<String> states = Lists.newArrayList(statesString.split(","));

        return states.stream().map(DeviceState::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

  
public class DeviceHistoryInState implements MyInterface<DeviceHistory> {
    private List<EventType> toStates(String statesString) {
        List<String> states = Lists.newArrayList(statesString.split(","));

        return states.stream().map(EventType::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And these enums:

```java
public enum EventType{
    NEW("N"), ACTIVE("A"), INACTIVE("I");
}
    
public enum DeviceState{
    REGISTRATED("R"), SUSPENDED("S"), DELETED("D");
}
```

The differences are:

- `DeviceInState implements MyInterface<Device>`; but `DeviceHistoryInState implements MyInterface<DeviceHistory>`
- `DeviceState::valueOf` is called in `DeviceInState`; but `EventTypes::valueOf` is called in `DeviceHistoryInState`

I have a couple of other classes like these so I would like to make a generic one. But I have no idea whether or not it is possible. How might I parameterize my classes or methods in a way that I can call the `::valueOf` method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DeviceState` and `EventType` are enums that are the element types of the list returned by the `toStates` method, which is overriden. Both classes implement the `MyInterface` interface. Could you show that interface?

Comment: Actually not these methods are overridden. These methods are just called from the overridden method. Well, if it's important for you... These codes are just part of the class. The interface I use is actually the Specification from Spring. I changed it because I don't think it's important. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html

Comment: Pass the class as parameter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837190/java-generics-get-class and get enum using class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357132/generic-enum-valueof-method-enum-class-in-parameter-and-return-enum-item

Comment: Declare the enum type as the 2nd generic type parameter and grab it in the constructor as shown in the q&a linekd in the previous comment. You might need an abstract class where to inherit from

Comment: Thing is I can pass my enum to the class like this. But I can't call the valueOf() because it's not an enum (for the code)

Comment: If you have enum class you can do `Enum.valueOf(YourEnum.class, value)`

Comment: „*…But I can't call the valueOf() because it's not an enum (for the code)…*“ – @stackstack293 — This comment is confusing to me. Why can you not call, say *`EventType.valueOf(String)`* in the *`DeviceHistoryInState.toStates(String)`* method? Can you edit your question with the error message that you get when such a call fails? — „*…Actually not these methods are overridden. These methods are just called from the overridden method…*“ —  Don't you think the *`@Overrides`* annotation should be removed then? It's confusing. And, therefore, makes it harder to know exactly what solution to propose.

Answer (score 0):

[*This is how I would do it*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/1Xk)…

```java
public interface State< E extends Enum< E > > { … }
```

Then my *`enums`* would implement that…

```java
…
public enum DeviceState implements State< DeviceState > { … }
…
public enum EventType implements State< EventType > { … }
…
```

> „*…Actually not these methods are overridden. These methods are just called from the overridden method…*“

Considering that you annotated the methods in your snippet with *`@Overrides`*, I found that to be a pretty confusing comment. To make things a little less confusing for myself,  [*my experimental implementation*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/1Xk) does actually override something…

```java
public class DeviceInState extends ToStateable< DeviceState > implements Specification< Device > {

    @Override
    public List< DeviceState > toStates( String statesString ) {
        
        List< String > states = asList( statesString.split( "," ) );

        return states.stream( ).map( String::trim ).map( DeviceState::valueOf ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I was able to call that successfully like…

```java
…
ToStateable< DeviceState > deviceToStateable = new DeviceInState( );
      
List< DeviceState > deviceStates = deviceToStateable.toStates( "SUSPENDED,REGISTERED,DELETED" );
      
ToStateable< EventType > eventToStateable = new DeviceHistoryInState( );
      
List< EventType > eventTypes = eventToStateable.toStates( "INACTIVE, NEW, ACTIVE"  );
…
```

Printing those objects out I could see…

```java
                                  [SUSPENDED, REGISTERED, DELETED]
                                           [INACTIVE, NEW, ACTIVE]
                                                         SUSPENDED
                                             EXPERIMENT SUCCESSFUL
```